# Detect the type of error when trying to load a HTML5 video using a source element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I just found out some differences between handling errors when a video is loaded using the `src` tag of the `<video>` element and handling error when a video is loaded using a `<source>` element.

For example, if I try to load a video stream that is not found (HTTP 404) using the `src` tag of the `video` element, an event is triggered and the element stores the error data:

**HTML**

```
<video src="http://not.found.url"></video>
```

**JS**

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('error', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.error); // Object
});
video.load();
```

The `video` element stores a `MediaError` object in `error`:

```
error: {
  code: 4,
  message: 'MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error'
}
```

However, when I try to load the same video stream using a `source` element:

**HTML**

```
<video>
  <source src="http://not.found.url">
</video>
```

**JS**

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var source = document.querySelector('source');

video.addEventListener('error', function(evt) {
  // This event is not triggered
  console.log(evt.target.error); // null
});

source.addEventListener('error', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.error); // null
});

video.load();
```

The `source` element error handler is the only one that catches the error but the error data is not stored anywhere. Neither the `video` element nor the `source` element stores an error object so, I can say an error has been triggered but I am not able to know the type of that error.

I would like to use the `source` element and be able to detect if the cause of the error has been a not valid video format, a 404 resource or any other reason.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Please fix your code, make it use correct string delimiters.

Comment: @CBroe Done! Thank you

Comment: I went through the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-load-algorithm) and, as far as I understand, there is no solution.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry, but the [error codes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaerror) will not help you with HTTP errors. However, the correct way to get the error code when using `<source>` elements is as follows:

```
<video class="video" autoplay controls>
    <source src="http://example.com/does-not-exist">
    <source src="http://example.com/corrupted-video">
    <source src="http://example.com/unsupported-video">
</video>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("video");
    var source = document.querySelector("source:last-child");
    // <source> elements are processed one by one until a usable source is found
    // if the last source failed then we know all sources failed

    video.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        console.log("<video> error");
        console.log(e.target.error);
        // e.target would be the <video> element
        // e.target.error -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaerror
    });

    source.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        console.log("<source> error");
        // e does not contain anything useful -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-source-error
        // e.target would be the <source> element
        // e.target.parentNode would be the <video> element
        // e.target.parentNode.error -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaerror
        // e.target.parentNode.networkState -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-networkstate
        console.log(e.target.parentNode.error);
        console.log(e.target.parentNode.networkState);
    });
</script>
```

While this approach does not tell you about HTTP errors, you might be able to get some extra information by:

1. Checking whether error was generated by `<source>` or `<video>`
2. Looking at [`error`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaerror) and [`networkState`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-networkstate)

Comment: Sadly if you are using source elements it does not seem like it's possible to get the MediaError object from the parent video element as you are attempting to do with `console.log(e.target.parentNode.error)`
I put your example into a [code pen](https://codepen.io/callumgare/pen/NWBXGKY) and ran it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but [all of them return null](https://imgur.com/Ri9RErv) :(